# Merge duplicate name and replace with first attribute id using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, replace, merge, duplicates

I have a XML where a node having id=D_7 has child nodes with id=D_7_B5 and id=D_8_B5 with the same name XYZ.
Further inside the child nodes, there are node inside each of them having duplicate name.
I want to get the result using XSLT wherein I get unique values of name and the id = D_8 be changed/merged to D_7 as shown in the output XML.

My Input XML:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hhsr>
    <hhs>
        <hh id="D_7">
            <name>N</name>
            <hhs>
            <hh id="D_7_B5">
                    <name>XYZ</name>
                    <hhs>
                        <hh id="D_7_B5_C1">
                            <name>DNC</name>
                        </hh>
                        <hh id="D_7_B5_C1">
                            <name>A</name>
                        </hh>
                    </hhs>
                </hh>
            <hh id="D_8_B5">
                    <name>XYZ</name>
                    <hhs>
                        <hh id="D_8_B5_C2">
                            <name>A</name>
                        </hh>
                        <hh id="D_8_B5_C3">
                            <name>B</name>
                        </hh>
                        <hh id="D_8_B5_C4">
                            <name>C</name>
                        </hh>
                        <hh id="D_8_B5_C5">
                            <name>D</name>
                        </hh>
                        <hh id="D_8_B5_C6">
                            <name>E</name>
                        </hh>
                        <hh id="D_8_B5_C7">
                            <name>F</name>
                        </hh>
                        <hh id="D_8_B5_C8">
                            <name>G</name>
                        </hh>
                        <hh id="D_8_B5_C9">
                            <name>H</name>
                        </hh>
                    </hhs>
                </hh>
    </hhs>
        </hh>
    </hhs>
</hhsr>
```

My Expected Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hhsr>
    <hhs>
        <hh id="D_7">
            <name>N</name>
            <hhs>
            <hh id="D_7_B5">
                    <name>XYZ</name>
                    <hhs>
                        <hh id="D_7_B5_C1">
                            <name>DNC</name>
                        </hh>
                        <hh id="D_7_B5_C1">
                            <name>A</name>
                        </hh>
                        <hh id="D_7_B5_C3">
                            <name>B</name>
                        </hh>
                        <hh id="D_7_B5_C4">
                            <name>C</name>
                        </hh>
                        <hh id="D_7_B5_C5">
                            <name>D</name>
                        </hh>
                        <hh id="D_7_B5_C6">
                            <name>E</name>
                        </hh>
                        <hh id="D_7_B5_C7">
                            <name>F</name>
                        </hh>
                        <hh id="D_7_B5_C8">
                            <name>G</name>
                        </hh>
                        <hh id="D_7_B5_C9">
                            <name>H</name>
                        </hh>
                    </hhs>
                </hh>
            </hhs>
        </hh>
    </hhs>
</hhsr>
```

Any help would be appreciable since I am new to XSLT.

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: After grouping, it is always deleting the first one. whereas I want to merge the duplicates after changing the id

Comment: If you want help with that, you will need to add your XSLT to your question.